# Spoof ongoing datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am looking for the simplest solution to spoof live `datetime`, specifically, I would like it to start at a specific time, say `2023-01-03 15:29`, and make it go on, so that the clock is ticking, so to speak.

There are plenty of ways to spoof current `datetime`, but I haven't find a way that would do so continuously, so the fake time keeps moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a file (say `spoofdt.py`) with a class that inherits `datetime.datetime` and contains a classmethod `now` that records the first time you call it, and returns a value based on the difference between that time and your desired time.

```
import datetime as dt

class datetime(dt.datetime):
    _ftime = dt.datetime(2023, 1, 3, 15, 29)
    _dtime = None

    @classmethod
    def now(cls, tz=None):
        if cls._dtime is None:
            cls._dtime = super(datetime, cls).now() - cls._ftime

        t = super(datetime, cls).now() - cls._dtime

        if tz is not None:
            return t.astimezone(tz)

        return t
```

Then instead of importing the `datetime` module, import `spoofdt` In your actual code:

```
import time

# instead of
# from datetime import datetime
# do this:
from spoofdt import datetime

for _ in range(10):
    print(datetime.now())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Which gives:

```
2023-01-03 15:29:00.000003
2023-01-03 15:29:01.001141
2023-01-03 15:29:02.001475
2023-01-03 15:29:03.002694
2023-01-03 15:29:04.003839
2023-01-03 15:29:05.005119
2023-01-03 15:29:06.005451
2023-01-03 15:29:07.006651
2023-01-03 15:29:08.007829
2023-01-03 15:29:09.009107


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

You can write similar implementations for [`today`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.today) and [`utcnow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow)

[Try it online](https://www.online-python.com/YOaj0RPSqo)

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is, instead of trying to 'spoof' datetime, just perform a "translation".

Basically, you just need to calculate the datetime you need to subtract from the current datatime.now() to reach your desired date.

desired_time = datatime.now - translation ==>
translation = datetime.now - desired_time

After that you can simply call datetime.now() - translation which will effectively progress the clock of your desired date.

Hope that makes sense and can work for you!